# How do I integrate my appium tests in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

I have a Windows 7 and I am testing an Android Native app using Appium using Java. The framework used is TestNG. I would like to use Jenkins for running smoke testing for builds available in Jenkins. My desired capabilities are listed in `@Before`. Can we dynamically paremetrize all of the following in Jenkins?

```
“automationName”
“platformName”
“platformVersion”
“deviceName”
“app”
“appPackage”
“appActivity“
```

If so How?

Now if I dynamically parametrize, what would happen to the desired capabilities in my script `@Before`

Comment: What have you tried? What did not exactly work in your solution? This is not exactly a "please suggest" site.

Comment: I need to know what can be parameterized in jenkins, how do I do that? and also What happens to my desired capabilities in my test script c:\appiumscripts\mytest.java?

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple,

in your class you have to include the code which will listen for input from jenkin job.

```
String deviceName = PropertyUtils.getProperty("deviceName");
```

and while you configure your job in Jenkins you have to include string parameter like the image below,
[image]

and while building, pass the parameter you want for each build,
[image]

The value which you  passing above will be processed in your code.

Comment: Do I have to use just this code? in @Before? String deviceName = PropertyUtils.getProperty("deviceName");